# Shadowcopy of AppDomain does not updating referenced dll

Tags: vb.net, winforms, appdomain, auto-update, shadow-copy

We have a main application (Winforms) with several dll's referenced containing Logic and UI Layers. After some research on how to perform auto-update in a winforms application, I found a solution using AppDomain and the ShadowCopies feature.
Another executable look for updates and makes the exchange of files.

Okay, but now, I got the following situation:

1. I start the main application (loaded through the new AppDomain).
2. I open a form that is in a referenced dll ("ReferenceA"). This dll is copied and instantiated from the copy. (Great!)
3. At this time the system receives an update with new versions of "ReferenceA" and "ReferenceB", and makes the exchange of files.
4. I open another form that is in "ReferenceB". This dll is copied and instantiated from the copy, but this dll also references "ReferenceA" that is not updated by ShadowCopy because it is already in the directory.
5. Now the system is running a newer version of "ReferenceB" with an older version of "ReferenceA". In my test I created a new method in "ReferenceA" then I obviously got the message: "Method not found".

Any suggestions on how I can solve this?